# adding link in .chm file

Tags: chm

I am working with SqlDoc 2. I have to do database's documentation. I will generate from this project .chm file.

My problem:

Example I have two function in my database, A and B. I want to add in A's descrption link to B. Is there something like html's

```
<a href="address">xxx</a>
```

?

If yes, what is 'address' in .chm file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An url, either absolute or relative.

Relative paths (e.g. ../x/y) are with respect to the current html file. Absolute (/x/y/) to the root of the CHM.

Absolute paths are bugged in some tools and better avoided

Comment: CHM contents IS html. So it is only more or less a difference in what the root is, compared to html.

Comment: when I add '<a href="address">xxx</a>' this program encode this text and I get string instead of a link

Comment: That's a problem of that specific program (sqldoc) then. Could you give an example?

Comment: when I generate html with `<a href="address">xxx</a>` I got `&lt;a href=&quot;address&quot;&gt;xxx&lt;/a&gt;` This program is doing `html.encode(my_text)`. I don't know how can I add link in this program..

Comment: I got message from sqlDoc producent. He said that it isn't possible to do in this version and they will try add this in new version. Thx for help